# Reset display brightness to factory defaults

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, high-sierra

A family member played with the display resolution and brightness settings. Fixing the resolution was easy, but it seems there's no way to restore default brightness. It's not a big deal (I just selected a brightness which is ok for me now) but I was wondering if in High Sierra there's a way to restore all the display settings to the factory defaults.

PS I'd prefer a solution which doesn't force me to reset **all** System Preferences to their factory defaults, just the display ones.

macOS High Sierra 10.13.5, MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2017)

Comment: You can copy each individual specification from that window, or choose ‘System Report’ at the bottom of the window to be able to view and copy all details (from Hardware and Software in the sidebar).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Default brightness is just ‘Automatically adjust brightness’ enabled. The brightness is constantly adjusted based on lighting conditions. If you disable this option, whatever the current brightness is that was automatically chosen is saved as the fixed brightness, so there is no default value.

Comment: I don’t know about macOS, but on iOS you can still “calibrate” how high and how low the automatic adjustment will go. For instance, by default iOS sets auto-brightness too bright in my bedroom with the lights off. I make it a habit to lower auto-brightness down to just above minimum on every new iPhone i get, and sure enough, iOS sets it exactly there in the same conditions.

Comment: Try dimming your screen to the lowest but still visible setting, you will notice that the screen will always be dimmer than it used to be and will never recover from that setting. Resetting things like SMC, PRAM doesn't reset brightness level. But it must be saved somewhere...

Answer (score 2):

Reset the PRAM https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht204063 . This will reset display settings.

Kind regards!